# Spark - pass column value to a udf and then get another column value inside udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a udf function which takes a column value, on condition of that column value i have to insert into this column another column value. my code is like :

```
val udfMobileDeviceId = udf { (os_type: String) => 
    if (os_type == "android")  $"androidIdfa" else  $"appleIdfv"
}
```

Comment: what are `androidIdfa` and `appleIdfv`? are they columns or just string values? you should consider using when function instead of udf

Answer (score 2):

either you pass those columns to the udf :

```
val udfMobileDeviceId = udf { (os_type: String, androidIfa:String, appleIdfv:String) => 
    if (os_type == "android")  androidIdfa else  appleIdfv
}
```

or even better: don't use an UDF for that, just do it in DataFrame API
:

```
df
.withColumn("mobileDeviceId", when($"os_type"==="andoid",$"androidIdfa").otherwise($"appleIdfv"))
```